# Dplyr joins multiple columns incorrectly

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, left-join

I am trying to perform a left join of multiple matching columns on two data frames - all columns are of class numeric:

The first is `test_trips`:

```
> test_trips
  start_station_longitude start_station_latitude end_station_longitude end_station_latitude
1               -122.4264               37.76142             -122.4312             37.78352
2               -122.3942               37.79539             -122.3942             37.79539
3               -121.8948               37.34876             -121.8771             37.32600
4               -122.4212               37.77379             -122.3997             37.78095
5               -122.4262               37.77643             -122.4035             37.78898
6               -122.2825               37.80369             -122.2948             37.80532
```

The second is `test_distance`:

```
> test_distance
  start_station_longitude start_station_latitude end_station_longitude end_station_latitude distance
1               -122.4264               37.76142             -122.4312             37.78352     3162
2               -122.3942               37.79539             -122.3942             37.79539        0
3               -121.8948               37.34876             -121.8771             37.32600     3591
4               -122.4212               37.77379             -122.3997             37.78095     2843
5               -122.4262               37.77643             -122.4035             37.78898     3088
6               -122.2825               37.80369             -122.2948             37.80532     1198
```

Notice how the coordinate values in each of the 4 columns from both tables are exactly the same.  Now why doesn't this left join work?

```
output <- dplyr::left_join(test_trips, test_distance, by=c( "start_station_longitude", "start_station_latitude",  "end_station_longitude", "end_station_latitude"))
```

the output produces **4 NA values**, which I do not understand - what is going wrong? My guess is that is has to do with the structure of `test_distance`, but I'm not sure how to modify it as `class()` informs me that it is a normal data.frame

```
> output
  start_station_longitude start_station_latitude end_station_longitude end_station_latitude distance
1               -122.4264               37.76142             -122.4312             37.78352       NA
2               -122.3942               37.79539             -122.3942             37.79539        0
3               -121.8948               37.34876             -121.8771             37.32600       NA
4               -122.4212               37.77379             -122.3997             37.78095       NA
5               -122.4262               37.77643             -122.4035             37.78898       NA
6               -122.2825               37.80369             -122.2948             37.80532     1198
```

here is the sample data:

```
> dput(test_trips)
structure(list(start_station_longitude = c(-122.4264353, -122.394203, 
-121.894797831774, -122.42123901844, -122.426244020462, -122.282497
), start_station_latitude = c(37.7614205, 37.795392, 37.3487586867448, 
37.7737932060887, 37.7764348192047, 37.8036865), end_station_longitude = c(-122.431157827377, 
-122.394203, -121.87712, -122.399749159813, -122.403452, -122.2948365
), end_station_latitude = c(37.783520835261, 37.795392, 37.3259984, 
37.7809545996075, 37.788975, 37.8053183)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

dput(test_distance)
structure(list(start_station_longitude = c(-122.4264353, -122.394203, 
-121.894797831774, -122.42123901844, -122.426244020462, -122.282497
), start_station_latitude = c(37.7614205, 37.795392, 37.3487586867448, 
37.7737932060887, 37.7764348192047, 37.8036865), end_station_longitude = c(-122.431157827377, 
-122.394203, -121.87712, -122.399749159813, -122.403452, -122.2948365
), end_station_latitude = c(37.783520835261, 37.795392, 37.3259984, 
37.7809545996075, 37.788975, 37.8053183), distance = c(3162, 
0, 3591, 2843, 3088, 1198)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.8 readr_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.3.0         jsonlite_1.6    
 [6] magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.3.1     rlang_0.3.1      rstudioapi_0.9.0 bindrcpp_0.2.2  
[11] tools_3.5.2      glue_1.3.0       purrr_0.3.0      hms_0.4.2        yaml_2.2.0      
[16] compiler_3.5.2   pkgconfig_2.0.2  tidyselect_0.2.5 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_2.0.1
```

Comment: I am not getting your problem. Restart R and repaste the sample data and perform the left join. When I merged, there were no NAs.

Comment: I restarted and get the same problem

Comment: I get no problems using `dplyr v0.7.8`.

Comment: very strange indeed - it simply does not work for me and I am running the same version of dplyr

Comment: Given that other using the same version can't replicate the problem can you provide your session info?

Comment: Yes I provided that above.  In the end I just used `merge()`   

`merge(test_distance, test_trips, by=c( "start_station_longitude", "start_station_latitude",  "end_station_longitude", "end_station_latitude"))`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:data.table]?

Comment: Maybe it is the R version.

Comment: It might be related to floating point precision, so can be platform specific. It is best to avoid merges on floating point numbers. You could create a dictionary of stations and map them to int, then join on int. To investigate try joining on rounded (down or up but not mixed) fields.

Comment: If you use data tables there is an option to set numeric rounding for floating point numbers so match can be accomplished with a tolerance